# Mostrar PDF no navegador sem imprimir ou gravar

Tags: pdf

Preciso visualizar documentos PDF na janela do navegador mas desejo que os mesmos sejam impedidos de imprimir ou gravar. 
Não quero porém alterar um por um dos arquivos colocando senha e tal, até porque isso pode ser quebrado.
Alguém pode sugerir alguma técnica ou visualizador que possa ser configurado a partir do PHP JS ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Infelizmente acredito que isso não é possível, já que, tudo que o navegador exibe pode ser baixado de alguma forma, só precisa saber onde procurar e como converter. Mas caso precise de exibir no navegador apenas, o exemplo abaixo pode ajudar.

Lembre-se que bloquear o usuário de mais nunca é uma boa ideia, nada vai impedir ele de tirar print e imprimir os prints. Eu mesmo já fiz isso com e-books de centenas de página. **Nunca duvide da disposição de seus usuários**.

Para indicar ao navegador que o arquivo deve ser visto no navegador:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: inline; filename="filename.pdf"
```

Para indicar que o arquivo deve ser baixado, em vez de visto:

```
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="filename.pdf"
```

As aspas em torno do nome de arquivo são necessárias se o nome do arquivo tiver caracteres especiais.

Comment: Concordo com você Renato, mas não é por isso que vou deixar a chave no contato do carro.  rss  Sua sugestão já me é de ajuda, porém os plug-ins Acrobat ou o do próprio FireFox, etc..  permitem facilmente a gravação ou impressão e podendo dificultar essas ações ganhamos em segurança.